# Post-concert routine for soloists?

Tags: classical-music, performing, solos

I'm curious about what happens when a soloist walks off stage after a performance. Where do they go? Where does the conductor go? Everything backstage is a mystery for me.

Comment: I've always headed straight for the bar… though even if I leave the stage first sometimes the brass section can beat me to it ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin you have a very appropriate avatar.

Comment: I don't think this question fits this forum. There could be other sites in the Stack Exchange network for this question. The question has many answers for different soloists and different situations. I once went to a concert with some friends. We were 4 or 5 people. After the concert we went backstage to get an autograph from the soloist. He was enlightened and suggested that we all went to a restaurant to eat, which we did. And lo and behold he paid the entire bill. That was indeed amazing.

Comment: You forgot to finish with  "Wrong answers only"    :-)

Answer (score 6):

In between pieces, a soloist and conductor will walk off stage and just stand in the wings briefly. It's a chance to pause, switch gears before the next piece, maybe have a drink of water. It allows time for any changes that need to happen on the stage, such as certain musicians leaving or entering, depending on who is needed for the next piece.

After a concert is over, if the venue provides dressing rooms for the soloist and conductor, they'll go there, rest, maybe change clothes, maybe greet guests. Again, it's a chance to switch gears, especially if they'll be going out to a reception afterwards.

Comment: There might be a reception in the foyer itself. / When I worked in an orchestra, I would greet friends who had attended the concert and then head home for supper and bed.

Answer (score 1):

First they go to their dressing room, pack their instrument away, get changed, possibly shower. If there's catering, they might stay at the venue for a while. If they're well known they might have to sign a few autographs or talk to well-wishers at the stage door. Then they'll do what anyone else does when they've finished work: go home (or to their hotel) or go out (to eat, drink, party...). Often the soloist and the conductor and their partners will go out to dinner.

Comment: I sort of skipped over the whole "putting away the instrument" part. Kind of important!